# javascript/jQuery: add items to list not working properly when check if exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, for-loop, if-statement

Edit: solved by this code

```
$("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event) {
if (event.which === 13) {
    var todoText = " " + $(this).val();
    var lis = $("li");
    if ($(lis).filter(function() {
            return $(this).text() == todoText;
        }).length === 0) {
        $('ul').append("<li> " + $.trim($(this).val()) + "</li>");
        $(this).val('').attr("placeholder", "Add New Todo").val("").removeClass('alert');
        return false;
    } else {
        $(this).attr("placeholder", "Todo exist").val("").addClass('alert');
        return false;
    }
  }
});
```

The filter function helps me to solve the problem. TXz a lot

Comment: You're welcome. What was the question you had?

Comment: Logic is flawed adding new one inside the loop...you need to check all of them first then when loop completes add it if it is not found

Answer (score 1):

Check the solution below. It is always better to manage the state somewhere rather than directly updating/checking the DOM.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var todoItems = ["Go to home", "Buy cavolo", "Fried chicken"];

  function renderItems() {
    var items = todoItems.map(function(item) {
      return '<li>' + item + '</li>'
    });
    $("#items").html(items.join(''));
  }
  renderItems();

  $("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
      if ($(this).val()) {
        if (todoItems.indexOf($(this).val()) == -1) {
          todoItems.unshift($(this).val());
          renderItems();
          $(this).val('')
        } else {
          alert("todo exist!");
        }
      }
    }
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Add New Item" />
<ul id="items">
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working

Comment: good to know, please upvote the answer if you think it's better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='text']").keypress(function(event) {
        if (event.which === 13  && $.trim($(this).val()) !== '') {
            if ($('ul li:contains('+$.trim($(this).val())+')').length ) {
                alert('todo exist!');
                return false;
            } else {
                $('ul').append('<li>'+$.trim($(this).val()) +'</li>');
                $(this).val('')
            }
        }                
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, very dry code. It works fine and i can remove a item from list without  changes

Comment: I add some code. Could you please check this? thank you